# css variable is not get applied to body tag

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass

I am implementing a `dark mode` theme with pure CSS in my `react` project and for that, I am using CSS variables with `:root` pseudo-class. Every color gets reflected for a particular element except `--backgroundColor` CSS property for the `body` tag and because of that the background color is not changing for the whole page. Can you guys please tell me what I am missing?

Thank you.

global-styles.scss:

```
:root {
  --backgroundColor: #FFF;
  --text: #363537;
  --cardBackground: #fff;
  ........
}

[data-theme='dark'] {
  --backgroundColor: #23272f;
  --text: #e3e3e3;
  --cardBackground: #343a46;
  ........
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background: var(--backgroundColor);
}

*,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 16px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: var(--text);
}
```

Comment: Have you inspected the body element using your browser dev tools, to see if it maybe gets its background color applied from a different rule with higher specificity or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is with the element that you're applying the `data-theme` attribute

if you apply it to the `body` then it will work, see for example https://jsfiddle.net/mg1bhrqj/

```
<body data-theme='dark'>
  <div>
    <h1>
      here
    </h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

If you apply the tag anywhere else it will not work

https://jsfiddle.net/18bnqhw4/

```
<div data-theme='dark'>
  <h1>
    here
  </h1>
</div>
```